# Loss Not Decreasing for a Bert from Scratch PyTorch Model

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I followed Aladdin Persson's [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0s0f995w14) to code up just the encoder portion of the transformer model in PyTorch, except I just used the Pytorch's multi-head attention layer. The model seems to produce the correct shape of data. However, during training, the training loss does not drop and the resulting model always predicts the same output of 0.4761. Dataset used for training is from the [Sarcasm Detection Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rmisra/news-headlines-dataset-for-sarcasm-detection) from Kaggle. Would appreciate any help you guys can give on errors that I have made.

```
import pandas as pd
from transformers import BertTokenizer
import torch.nn as nn
import torch
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import ReduceLROnPlateau
import math

df = pd.read_json("Sarcasm_Headlines_Dataset_v2.json", lines=True)

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
encoded_input = tokenizer(df['headline'].tolist(), return_tensors='pt',padding=True)

X = encoded_input['input_ids']
y = torch.tensor(df['is_sarcastic'].values).float()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify = y)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

class TransformerBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,embed_dim, num_heads, dropout, expansion_ratio):
        super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__()
        self.attention = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim, num_heads)
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(embed_dim)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(embed_dim)
        self.feed_forward = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(embed_dim, expansion_ratio*embed_dim),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(expansion_ratio*embed_dim,embed_dim)
        )
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, value, key, query):
        attention, _ = self.attention(value, key, query)
        x=self.dropout(self.norm1(attention+query))
        forward = self.feed_forward(x)
        out=self.dropout(self.norm2(forward+x))
        return out

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    #the vocab size is one more than the max value in the X matrix.
    def __init__(self,vocab_size=30109,embed_dim=128,num_layers=1,num_heads=4,device="cpu",expansion_ratio=4,dropout=0.1,max_length=193):
        super(Encoder,self).__init__()
        
        self.device = device
        self.word_embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size,embed_dim)
        self.position_embedding = nn.Embedding(max_length,embed_dim)
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(
            [
                TransformerBlock(embed_dim,num_heads,dropout,expansion_ratio) for _ in range(num_layers)
            ]
        )
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.classifier1 = nn.Linear(embed_dim,embed_dim)
        self.classifier2 = nn.Linear(embed_dim,1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    
    def forward(self,x):
        N, seq_length = x.shape
        positions = torch.arange(0,seq_length).expand(N, seq_length).to(self.device)
        out = self.dropout(self.word_embedding(x) + self.position_embedding(positions))
        
        for layer in self.layers:
            #print(out.shape)
            out = layer(out,out,out)
        
        #Get the first output for classification
        #Pooled output from hugging face is: Last layer hidden-state of the first token of the sequence (classification token) further processed by a Linear layer and a Tanh activation function.
        #Pooled output from hugging face will be different from out[:,0,:], which is the output from the CLS token.
        out = self.relu(self.classifier1(out[:,0,:]))
        out = self.classifier2(out)
        
        return out

torch.cuda.empty_cache()
net = Encoder(device=device)
net.to(device)

batch_size = 32
num_train_samples = X_train.shape[0]
num_val_samples = X_test.shape[0]

criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(),lr=1e-5)
scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, 'min', patience=5)

val_loss_hist=[]
loss_hist=[]
epoch = 0
min_val_loss = math.inf

print("Training Started")

patience = 0

for _ in range(100):
    
    epoch += 1
        
    net.train()
    epoch_loss = 0
    
    permutation = torch.randperm(X_train.size()[0])
    
    for i in range(0,X_train.size()[0], batch_size):
        
        indices = permutation[i:i+batch_size]
        
        features=X_train[indices].to(device)
        labels=y_train[indices].reshape(-1,1).to(device)
        
        output = net.forward(features)
        loss = criterion(output, labels)

        optimizer.zero_grad() 
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        epoch_loss+=loss.item()
        
    epoch_loss = epoch_loss / num_train_samples * num_val_samples
    loss_hist.append(epoch_loss)
    
    #print("Eval")
    net.eval()
    epoch_val_loss = 0
    
    permutation = torch.randperm(X_test.size()[0])
    
    for i in range(0,X_test.size()[0], batch_size):
        
        indices = permutation[i:i+batch_size]
        
        features=X_test[indices].to(device)
        labels = y_test[indices].reshape(-1,1).to(device)
        
        output = net.forward(features)
        loss = criterion(output, labels)        

        epoch_val_loss+=loss.item()
    
    val_loss_hist.append(epoch_val_loss)
    
    scheduler.step(epoch_val_loss)
    
    #if epoch % 5 == 0:
    print("Epoch: " + str(epoch) + " Train Loss: " + format(epoch_loss, ".4f") + ". Val Loss: " + format(epoch_val_loss, ".4f") + " LR: " + str(optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr']))
            
    if epoch_val_loss < min_val_loss:
        min_val_loss = epoch_val_loss
        torch.save(net.state_dict(), "torchmodel/weights_best.pth")
        print('\033[93m'+"Model Saved"+'\033[0m')
        patience = 0
        
    else:
        patience += 1
    
    if (patience == 10):
        break
        
print("Training Ended")
```